# No results in LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am completely new to LINQ and want to start learning LINQ to XML. I have read the documentation and tried to find an answer online, to no avail.

This is the XML I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<parameters>
  <view name="some_view">
    <col name="name">
      <width>150</width>
    </col>
  </view>
  <view name="anotherview">
    <col name="colname">
      <format>D12</format>
    </col>
  </view>
</parameters>
```

and I try to fetch the `view` node of view `some_view` like this:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load("params.xml");
var test = from _view in root.Descendants("view") where 
     _view.Attribute("name").Equals("some_view") select _view;
```

The `root` element is there, because a call to `root.Descendants("view")` gives me two nodes. But when I run the LINQ as above, I get no result, where I expect to get the first `view` node from the XML.

Comment: *"root.Descendants("view") gives me two nodes."* This is correct. You have two `view` nodes in your XML. What's your question?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I want to fetch the node which has attribute `name` set to a certain value.

Comment: @BartFriederichs To access `attribute` value use `_view.Attribute("name").value` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently compare the attribute with `some_view`. You need to compare its value with that string. Do that by casting the attribute to `string` and using the equality operator:

```
var test = from _view in root.Descendants("view") where 
    ((string)_view.Attribute("name")) == "some_view" select _view;
```

This ensures that your code doesn't crash with a `NullReferenceException` if a `view` node doesn't have the `name` attribute.

Comment: No need for `Equals` here?

Comment: Out of interest, if `view` doesn't have a `name` what happens when it tries to cast to `string`, why *doesn't* it fail?

Comment: `Equals` is a bad idea here, because `((string)_view.Attribute("name"))` will be `null` if the `name` attribute doesn't exist. Using `Equals` would result in a `NullReferenceException` in that case.

Comment: @RGraham: That's just how the API is designed. See my previous comment for the result.

Comment: @KendallFrey I always thought `==` didn't work for strings. I guess that came from some Java background, where it is reference equality.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: Yeah, that's not the case in .NET. `string` overloads the equality operator to perform a value comparison.

Answer (score 3):

I think you were missing the .`Value` from the attribute:

```
var test = (from _view in xml.Descendants("view")
            where _view.Attribute("name") != null && _view.Attribute("name").Value == "some_view" 
            select _view).SingleOrDefault();
```

Does what you want

Comment: This is bad code. It will crash if there is no `name` attribute on at least one `view` node. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18697621/572644) for a safe way to perform this query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I hadn't considered that so have included this in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the call to `XAttribute.Equals`. `XAttribute` is a reference type which although it *could* override the Equals method, would have misleading behaviour if it did so. I expect you will want `Attribute("name").Value.Equals("some_view")`.

Not guaranteeing that's the only problem however - I'm not in a position to test at the moment.

Comment: This is bad code. It will crash if there is no `name` attribute on at least one `view` node. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18697621/572644) for a safe way to perform this query.

Comment: I didn't intend to indicate that the code snippet I supplied should be used instead - it just demonstrates a minimal correction to the most obvious problem in the OP's code. I'd hope it'd be fairly obvious that it has deficiencies of its own which you've rightly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

use **_view.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("some_view")** instead.

Comment: put more description for your solution please!

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct you just have to access `attribute value`.

```
  XElement root = XElement.Load("params.xml");
   var test = from _view in root.Descendants("view") where 
              _view.Attribute("name").value.Equals("some_view") 
              select _view;
```